# Limit memory exec() php it's true?

Tags: php, memory

I'm writing a PHP script. This script executes an .exe script in c++. This script uses open cv libraries to detect text in image. The script works fine until the point heavier images are being processed. When this happens the execution stops and I don't know why.

I think there are some memory limitation but I don't find this information in any web.

How can I fix this?

The c++ process uses approximately  1,5GB of memory and I execute the c++ like:

```
$argumento = 'TDetect\DeteccioText uploads/'.$image_name;
$result = exec($argumento);
```

Comment: php's memory limits will not apply to the external .exe. that'll be a completely separate process. Have you tried running the exe on that larger image directly WITHOUT using php to exec? If it's slow that way too, then you know it's not a php problem.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what environment you are using. Linux/Windows and the version. it is possible on linux it blocks the execution due to child process memory limitations.

Comment: Most likely your background process is being interrupted or it is timing out. Try to look into the command `nohup`. Or do as stated by the others, they are also correct.

Comment: `$image_name = 'foo | rm -rf *';` uh oh.

Comment: @MarcB Yes, I try to use c++ directly without php and result is correct.
 I use windows 7 to execute all the proces.
I think that I find the solution I use this sentences in the beginning of my php code. 

ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1200);

I think that I solve the problem, after work I try to use this.

Thanks